# Help in constructing a GQL query for a one to many relationship

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-models

**A] Problem Summary:**

I have one to many data models in my project. I need help constructing a query to get the “many” side data object based on the key of the “one” side data object.

Please refer to "EDIT#1" for the code that has worked, but still inefficient.

**B] Problem details:**

1] I have “UserReportedCountry” (one) to “UserReportedCity” (many) , “UserReportedCity” (one) to “UserReportedStatus” (many) data model relationships.

2] The key for UserReportedCountry is a country_name , example -- “unitedstates”.
The key for UserReportedCity is country_name:city_name, example “unitedstates:boston.
UserReportedStatus has no special key name.

3] I have the users country and city name in my python code and I want to retrieve all “UserReportedStatus” objects based on the city key name which is “county_name:city_name”

**C] Code excerpts:**

1] database models:

```
class UserReportedCountry(db.Model):
  country_name = db.StringProperty( required=True,
                          choices=['Afghanistan','Aring land Islands']
                         )

class UserReportedCity(db.Model):
  country = db.ReferenceProperty(UserReportedCountry, collection_name='cities')
  city_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)   

class UserReportedStatus(db.Model):
  city = db.ReferenceProperty(UserReportedCity, collection_name='statuses')
  status = db.BooleanProperty(required=True)
  date_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

2] query I have tried so far:

```
def get_data_for_users_country_and_city(self,users_country,users_city):
    key_name_for_user_reported_city = users_country + ":" + users_city
    return UserReportedStatus.all().filter('city.__key__=', key_name_for_user_reported_city ).fetch(limit=10)
```

**D] Technologies being used**

1] Python

2] Google App engine

3] Django

4] Django models.

**[EDIT#1]**

I have tried the following mechanism to query the status objects based on the given city and country. This has worked, but i believe this is an inefficient mechanism to perform the task.

```
def get_data_for_users_country_and_city(self,users_country,users_city):
    key_name_for_user_reported_city = users_country + ":" + users_city
    city_object = UserReportedCity.get_by_key_name( key_name_for_user_reported_city )
    return UserReportedStatus.gql('WHERE city=:1', city_object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last query looks correct and I don't see any problem of inefficiency on it; in fact querying `by_key_name` is pretty fast and efficient.

I think you have room of improvement on your *normalized RDMBS oriented* Models design instead; since GAE does not support JOINS, after the `get_data_for_users_country_and_city` call, you will end in hitting the datastore too much to fetch the `city_name` and `country_name` properties when dereferenced.

What could you do? *Denormalization* and *prefetching*.

1. Add a `country_name` property in the `UserReportedCity` model definition
2. [Prefetch ReferenceProperty](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine)  to retrieve the `UserReportedCity` object for each `UserReportedStatus` object

Comment: Thanks @systempuntoout for your response. If i put the country_name in the city model, then should i still keep the UserReportedCountry model ?

Comment: It really depends on your application if it is worth keeping or not; I mean, if for example your app shows the list of Country in a combo, you still could read the list of countries using the UserReportedCountry model.